# Почему прогресс бар вытесняется за пределы экрана, как это исправить?

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/strength"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/full_wifi" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ssid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/editTextColor"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"

            android:textSize="13sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="right"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас контейнер с прогресс-баром находится вне корневого лэйаута:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="right"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```